# How to clean (delete) temporary files if they exist in Ubuntu OS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, temp

I need to do a lot of cleaning in my virtual machine whose operating system is Ubuntu.

Normally in Windows, there is this kind of directory that contains temporary files and that should be cleaned:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp
```

Does it exist such a directory in Ubuntu? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

run this in shell:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Comment: …and hope there are no processes that are currently using any of those files.

Comment: Desperate times call for desperate measures :)

Comment: @dimon thanks working fine....!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu and other unices, it is `/tmp`. It is automatically cleaned up when the machine reboots.

Comment: I reboots my systems but there is no files are automatically deleted in /tmp.

Comment: 1. Are you rebooting the Ubuntu guest? 2. As a test, create a file in `/tmp` (e.g. `touch /tmp/file`) and reboot and see if it's still there.

Comment: This a good read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up

Comment: I test already and no such file is deleted after reboot.